# Spark SQL UDF with varargs contains null and may return null

Tags: apache-spark-sql, udf

Spark sql default provides a function greatest(Column... exprs) which will "Returns the greatest value of the list of values, skipping null values."

But recently we got a requirement that we needs a function my_greatest(Column... exprs) that

- **if exprs contains null, then return null**
- otherwise return the greatest value of the list of values

I checked the UDF of Spark SQL, it seems that I can not defined varargs contains null and can not return null.

Is there any way to implement this? thank you.

Comment: If possible wrap all values into a string then pass it as one argument. you can write your logic in UDF.

Comment: you can use Hive Generic UDF for varargs.

Comment: Yes, thanks mrsrinivas.I copy the code of hive ql [greatest](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/generic/GenericUDFGreatest.java) function. and register it by  `FunctionRegistry.registerTemporaryUDF("my_greatest", com.xxx.yyy.MyGreatest`)